# SQL Server Management studio vs other editions

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between SQL Server Management Studio and SQL Server Express edition and which is better? I can't understand the relationship between these two. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4):

You are talking about 2 different things.

**SQL Server Express** is one edition (a variant) of SQL Server.

**SQL Server Management Studio** is a tool that you use to access SQL Server (any edition). You would use it, for instance, to *access* SQL Server Express, but **not** as a *replacement* of SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 0):

**Sql Server Management Studio:**
It is the tool used to administering, configuring  of sqlserver components by using script 
editors and graphical tools

sqlserver express is the express edition of sqlserver

You can find the list of sql server editions from following link

http://www.sqlserverspace.com/sqlservereditioncomparison.html

**In simple words it(sqlserver management studio) is the interface to access sqlserver(database) of any edition(Express,Enterprise,Developer etc)**

Answer (score -1):

Yea.

Management Studio is Management Studio. There are not various differences. THe DB has various capabilities, but management studio is management studio.